# How to fix error "No subshaders can run on this graphics device" - Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I am using Unity 5.1.0 to develop shader. But I am a newbie. After I write this shader, its thow this warning

> "No Subshaders can run on this graphics device"

and I cannot use this shader on Unity Editor.

I am using Android mode in Unity Edtior. This is my shader code. Could anyone fix this bug for me? Thanks in advance!

```js
Shader "Sprite/MyShader" {
Properties {
[PerRendererData]  _MainTex ("Sprite Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
 _Color ("Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
 _Stencil ("Stencil Ref", Float) = 0
 _StencilReadMask ("Stencil ReadMask", Float) = 255
 _StencilComp ("Stencil Comparison", Float) = 8
}
SubShader { 
 Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" "PreviewType"="Plane" "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="true" }
 Pass {
  Tags { "QUEUE"="Transparent" "IGNOREPROJECTOR"="true" "RenderType"="Transparent" "PreviewType"="Plane" "CanUseSpriteAtlas"="true" }
  ZWrite Off
  Cull Off
  Fog { Mode Off }
  Stencil {
   Ref [_Stencil]
   ReadMask [_StencilReadMask]
   Comp [_StencilComp]
   Pass Replace
  }
  Blend One OneMinusSrcAlpha
  ColorMask 0
Program "vp" {
SubProgram "opengl " {
Bind "vertex" Vertex
Bind "color" Color
Bind "texcoord" TexCoord0
Vector 5 [_Color]
"!!ARBvp1.0
PARAM c[6] = { program.local[0],
  state.matrix.mvp,
  program.local[5] };
MUL result.color, vertex.color, c[5];
MOV result.texcoord[0].xy, vertex.texcoord[0];
DP4 result.position.w, vertex.position, c[4];
DP4 result.position.z, vertex.position, c[3];
DP4 result.position.y, vertex.position, c[2];
DP4 result.position.x, vertex.position, c[1];
END
# 6 instructions, 0 R-regs
"
}
SubProgram "d3d9 " {
Bind "vertex" Vertex
Bind "color" Color
Bind "texcoord" TexCoord0
Matrix 0 [glstate_matrix_mvp]
Vector 4 [_Color]
"vs_2_0
dcl_position0 v0
dcl_color0 v1
dcl_texcoord0 v2
mul oD0, v1, c4
mov oT0.xy, v2
dp4 oPos.w, v0, c3
dp4 oPos.z, v0, c2
dp4 oPos.y, v0, c1
dp4 oPos.x, v0, c0
"
}
SubProgram "d3d11 " {
Bind "vertex" Vertex
Bind "color" Color
Bind "texcoord" TexCoord0
ConstBuffer "$Globals" 32
Vector 16 [_Color]
ConstBuffer "UnityPerDraw" 336
Matrix 0 [glstate_matrix_mvp]
BindCB  "$Globals" 0
BindCB  "UnityPerDraw" 1
"vs_4_0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"
}
SubProgram "d3d11_9x " {
Bind "vertex" Vertex
Bind "color" Color
Bind "texcoord" TexCoord0
ConstBuffer "$Globals" 32
Vector 16 [_Color]
ConstBuffer "UnityPerDraw" 336
Matrix 0 [glstate_matrix_mvp]
BindCB  "$Globals" 0
BindCB  "UnityPerDraw" 1
"vs_4_0_level_9_1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"
}
}
Program "fp" {
SubProgram "opengl " {
SetTexture 0 [_MainTex] 2D 0
"!!ARBfp1.0
PARAM c[1] = { { 0.099975586 } };
TEMP R0;
TEMP R1;
TEX R0, fragment.texcoord[0], texture[0], 2D;
MUL R0, R0, fragment.color.primary;
SLT R1.x, R0.w, c[0];
MUL result.color.xyz, R0, R0.w;
MOV result.color.w, R0;
KIL -R1.x;
END
# 6 instructions, 2 R-regs
"
}
SubProgram "d3d9 " {
SetTexture 0 [_MainTex] 2D 0
"ps_2_0
dcl_2d s0
def c0, -0.09997559, 0.00000000, 1.00000000, 0
dcl v0
dcl t0.xy
texld r0, t0, s0
mul r0, r0, v0
add_pp r1.x, r0.w, c0
cmp_pp r1.x, r1, c0.y, c0.z
mov_pp r1, -r1.x
texkill r1.xyzw
mov_pp r1.w, r0
mul_pp r1.xyz, r0, r0.w
mov_pp oC0, r1
"
}
SubProgram "d3d11 " {
SetTexture 0 [_MainTex] 2D 0
"ps_4_0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"
}
SubProgram "d3d11_9x " {
SetTexture 0 [_MainTex] 2D 0
"ps_4_0_level_9_1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"
}
}
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the unity tag, as it is for a completely different thing.

Comment: But i think it belong to Unity 3D :)

Comment: You shouldn't use the `c#` nor `unity3d-editor` tags either, this has nothing to do with them.

Comment: @CoderVN then you should use unity3d tag, but I have changed that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually shader files in Unity are writen in Cg/HLSL language, which Unity then compiles into lots of platform variants. When about to render on screen, it chooses one the device supports.

What you posted is a **compiled** shader. It was compiled for four `SubPrograms`, namely `opengl`, `d3d9`, `d3d11` and `d3d11_9x` (you'll find them in the text).

[Here's the list of supported rendering APIs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-ShaderPrograms.html):

```
d3d9 - Direct3D 9.
d3d11 - Direct3D 11.
opengl - OpenGL.
gles - OpenGL ES 2.0.
gles3 - OpenGL ES 3.0.
metal - iOS Metal.
d3d11_9x - Direct3D 11 9.x feature level, as commonly used on WSA/WP8 platforms.
xbox360 - Xbox 360.
xboxone - Xbox One.
ps3 - PlayStation 3.
ps4 - PlayStation 4.
psp2 - PlayStation Vita.
```

Apparently your computer doesn't support any of the four already compiled, so it cannot render it at all. Or maybe it's because your are on Android mode. Regardless, if you are a newbie, you'd better find the original Cg/HLSL code, and work with that.